# jQuery draggable scrollable container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I currently have a simple draggable list, which I want to be inside a div ( the items ) and scrollable.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable();
```

I currently have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/660/

But as you can see, the draggable elements stay inside the elements container, I want them to be able to drag out, but also the ability to scroll inside the elements container as soon as there are more elements, than the container long is.

Can anyone get me on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery handles interactions like these with a helper object that you can append to another DOM element:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '#outer'
});
```

Then you can have a droppable somewhere:

```
$('#dropspace').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        window.alert('Element dropped at left: ' + ui.position.left + '; top: ' + ui.position.top);
    }
});
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/662/

You still need to move the actual dom element to where it was dropped, or recreate it depending on what you're going to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

The option `helper: 'clone'` makes a clone of the item you're dragging automatically so that it can be dragged out of the container:

```
jQuery(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    appendTo: 'body'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a good question, because it reveals how JQuery handles draggable elements. Your draggable elements cannot be dragged outside of the parent "elements" div, because it represents per se the restriction for them.

So you could renounce to use the parent element "elements", then you can drag them wherever you want.

Or you can make the parent element bigger, using width and height with 100%.

If you use Draggable inside a bootstrap container you would notice that they can be dragged till to the boundaries of the container, but never ever outside of it.

You may also try to put the draggable elements outside the parent element, with an absolute position.

CSS:

```
.draggable{
   width: 60px;
   z-index: 15;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: absolute;
}

#elements{
        overflow: scroll;
        position:absolute;
        left:20px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
        z-index:5;
        padding:10px;
        font-size: 10px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="elements"/>

<div id="" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```