# How to scroll page up/down during dragging the image on grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a sample code and I want to drag the bottom image to top position Or top image to bottom position but scrolling up/down doesn't work.

I was trying to achieve this by using https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yExKoj
But it couldn't help me.

This also couldn't help me
[Page won't vertically scroll when dragging a draggable item down/up the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775974/page-wont-vertically-scroll-when-dragging-a-draggable-item-down-up-the-page)

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <style>
            [draggable=true] {
                cursor: move;
            }
            .img-box {
                padding: 2px;
                aspect-ratio: 1/1;
            }

                .img-box > img {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div draggable="true" class="col-3 img-box">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could able to doing this by using

Element.scrollIntoView()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView